# Does Active Directory Certificate Services support Card Verifiable Certificates?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, active-directory

Does Active Directory Certificate Services support accepting requests for, and generation of, Card Verifiable Certificates (TR-03110)?

If so, in which version of Windows Server was the functionality introduced?

I have been unable to find any reference to Card Verifiable Certificates in the Active Directory Certificate Services documentation or by searching online, so it looks to me like this might not be supported, but it would be good to know definitively.